# Getting error in lower casing the alphabet

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a large data of movie conversation:-
Cornell Movie Dialogs.
I am trying to convert them into lower cased

```
    def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r"i'm", "i am", text)
    text = re.sub(r"he's", "he is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"she's", "she is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"that's", "that is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"what's", "what is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"where's", "where is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'re", "are", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'d", "would", text)
    text = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"can't", "cannot", text)
    text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}+=-|.?,]", "", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ll", "will", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ve", "have", text)
    return text

#cleaning the questions
clean_questions = []
for question in questions:
    clean_questions.append(clean_text(question))
```

and I get the following callback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-4733a5502cb3>", line 3, in <module>
    clean_questions.append(clean_text(question))

  File "<ipython-input-16-a9a9890808b2>", line 2, in clean_text
    text = text.lower()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong and how to correct it would be greatly appreciated!!! Thank you!!

Comment: But how does `questions` look like???, if that's post that will be useful information for users, then maybe will get answers

Comment: It looks like `question` is of type list. Show sample `questions`

Comment: The error aside, `re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}+=-|.?,]", "", text)` might not be doing what you want it to do because of the middle `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways, i answer even tho `questions` list is not shown:

It depends on the list, if it's a nested list (i thing it is because from error), i.e:

```
l=[['ABC','XYZ'],'BlA']
```

It won't work, because, there are lists as elements, so flatten it:

```
x=[]
for i in l:
    if type(i) is list:
        x.extend(i)
    else:
        x.append(i)
```

Now:

```
print(x)
```

Is:

```
['ABC','XYZ','BlA']
```

Then your code to `x` will work, OTOH:

```
['A','B','C']
```

Meaning all strings, it will work as expected too.

Answer (score 0):

Str.lower() does not work on entire lists but rather on seperate strings. You could fix it by doing something like this:

```
for i in range(len(text)): text[i].lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Lower() is a string method and won't work on lists. Use a loop to iterate through the list and Lower() each element